# Every time I open terminal on macos,it shows these error message: Last login: -bash: complete: -D: invalid option complete: usage

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

the error message:

```
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [-X filterpat] [-F function] [-C command] [name ...]
-bash: complete: -D: invalid option
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [-X filterpat] [-F function] [-C command] [name ...]
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

When bash starts, it runs some scripts by default. What scripts are run, [depends on several settings and is situation-dependent](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

The [`completion` bash buildin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) enables an user to use <kbd>tab</kbd> to automatically complete commands and filenames in the bash shell. Under bash, `completion` is often started from the `~/.bashrc` or the `~/.bash_profile` script.

It seems that there is an error one of those scripts. The `complete` command complains that there is an illegal option in the way the application is called.

Long story short: check the `~/.bashrc` file for errors.

Answer (score 0):

### MacOS issue?

For me (MacOS Ventura 13.6) the error `-bash: complete: -D: invalid option` was caused by the system installed `/bin/bash` shell being too old:

```sh
❯ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin22)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I already have a newer version installed via Brew (https://brew.sh -- `brew install bash`), but it's not being used by default:

```sh
❯ /opt/homebrew/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin22.1.0)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

### MacOS solution!

The solution was for me to run the following two commands:

```sh
sudo bash -c 'echo /opt/homebrew/bin/bash >> /etc/shells'
chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```